# Selenium 4.0.0-B Grid, GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT not working properly

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-grid, selenium4

I am using Selenium 4 (python) to execute a browser on SE Grid with Docker-compose.

When I previously executed it while I was working with Selenium 3, the GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=1500, it used to work perfectly, but now when I changed to Se 4.0.0-beta-3, it just doesn't respects the time grid. Did any parameter changed since the update??

This is the part of my dockerfile associated to de GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.0.0-beta-3-prerelease-20210319
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4449:4444"
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    environment:
      - GRID_TIMEOUT=1500
      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=1500
      - GRID_MAX_SESSION=2
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very end of this selenium ticket I saw that the ENV name is as follows: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8974
The convention followed is "SE_component-name_option-name with underscores".
So for node max sessions, it would be: `SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=3`

Unfortunately I think they got rid of `GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT`
There is a `SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT` which might be the same.